# Initializing Row with Default Values

Tags: postgresql, default-value

I have a table. This table has no rows in it currently and every column has some sort of default value.

I do not wish to actually insert any data, but I want 1 row to appear with all of the default values. How do I do this? This does not work:

```
insert into testing.constants values defaults;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the syntax is `default values`:

```
insert into testing.constants default values;
```

You might be confused with setting a default for one particular column.  For instance:

```
insert into testing.constants(col1, col2)
    values (default, default);
```

Comment: That's what it was. Darn. Thanks Gordon!